# display data from json file in angular material table using loop

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I'm trying to display the data contained in my json file in my angular material table for that I try to make a loop but I don't know how to do it.

I don't know if my json is correct or not, in my json my 2 objects have the same name.

my question is what is wrong with my code ? in my table there is nothing displayed

Thanks for your help

**html**

```html
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8">
    <!-- type Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="dechets.type">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>type</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.type}}</td>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- weight Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="dechets.weight">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>weight</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element..weight}}</td>
    </ng-container>

    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
</table>
```

**ts.file**

```
ELEMENT_DATA: Itype[] = [];
  displayedColumns: any[] = ['dechets.type', 'dechets.weight'];
  dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<any>(this.ELEMENT_DATA);

  constructor(private authService: AuthenticationService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getAllDetails();
  }

  public getAllDetails() {
    let resp = this.authService.getDetails();
    resp.subscribe(resp => {
      this.dataSource.data = resp.reduce((acc, item) => {
        acc.push(item.dechets);
        console.log(item.dechets);
        return acc;
      }, []);
    });
  }
```

````
**json.file**

```json
[
    {
        "date_collect": "02/01/2014",
        "code_client": "ID1A",
        "dechets": [
            {
                "type": "bouteille_plastique",
                "weight": 2.9
            },
            {
                "type": "canette",
                "weight": 3.5
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "date_collect": "03/01/2014",
        "code_client": "ID1A",
        "dechets": [
            {
                "type": "bouteille_plastique",
                "weight": 3.7
            },
            {
                "type": "canette",
                "weight": 5.4
            }
        ]
    }
]
````

Comment: You have said that something is wrong, but you are not even asking a question. What is your question?

Comment: my question is what is wrong with my code ?

Comment: I don't know. How do you know there's something wrong with it? I see no information about anything being wrong in your post.

Comment: I updated my post

Comment: try having the datasource be just an array and setting it with `this.dataSource = resp as Itype[]` instead of `this.dataSource.data = resp as Itype[]`

Comment: I tried to change but I have this error: `Type 'Itype[]' is not assignable to type 'MatTableDataSource<Itype>'.`

Comment: I mean to make it like `dataSource: Itype[] = [];` instead of making it as a new `MatTableDataSource`

Comment: ok now same probleme still nothing displayed, I'm a beginner and I'm trying to do and understand the best I can

Comment: did you use `console.log(resp);` to verify you can even get the correct data?

Comment: it returns me an observable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

**.ts**

```
ELEMENT_DATA: Itype[] = [];
displayedColumns: string[] = ['dechets.type', 'dechets.weight'];
dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<any>(this.ELEMENT_DATA);
constructor(private authService: AuthenticationService) { }
ngOnInit() {
    this.getAllDetails();
}

public getAllDetails() {
    let resp = this.authService.getDetails();
    resp.subscribe(resp => { 
       this.dataSource.data = resp.reduce((acc, item) => {
          acc.push(...item.dechets);
          return acc;
       }, []);
    });
}
```

**Template**

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8">
    <!-- type Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="dechets.type">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>type</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.type}}</td>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- weight Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="dechets.weight">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>weight</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.weight}}</td>
    </ng-container>

    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
</table>
```

---

if you did everything right,
I can see only one problem with your code.
Look at your data item structure is this

```
{
        "date_collect": "02/01/2014",
        "code_client": "ID1A",
        "dechets": [
            {
                "type": "bouteille_plastique",
                "weight": 2.9
            },
            {
                "type": "canette",
                "weight": 3.5
            }
        ]
    }
```

And in your table you are trying to get `element.dechets.weight`, but `element.dechet` is an array where you have 2 objects,
can you please check will this show the data in your table?

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8">
    <!-- type Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="dechets.type">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>type</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.dechets[0].type}}</td>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- weight Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="dechets.weight">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>weight</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.dechets[0].weight}}</td>
    </ng-container>

    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: your item `dechets` is an array and if you will see the HTML I am getting the `type` and `weight` from the first(0) element of the Array.

Comment: Basically the problem is that your data is 2 dimensional, but tables only show 1 dimensional data

Comment: @TrevorKropp yes, so the problem can be resolved by map, the main thing we already know what is the problem, I will update the Answer in a few mins

Comment: How can I get it to show me both types? bouteille plastique et canette ?

Comment: you can also do for the type `td`, `{{element.dechets.map((next) => next.type).join(",")}}` if you want a row for every date and client code combination

Comment: I still have nothing displayed but when I console log item.dechets it returns an array with the data, I updated my code with the changes

Comment: @Herve oh you changed your code wrong. Please change `acc.push(item.dechets);` to `acc.push(...item.dechets);` and please replace html as well

Comment: finally it works all displays well but I have this error when I change the code: `Type '{ type: string; weight: number; }' must have a '[Symbol.iterator]()' method that returns an iterator.`

Comment: hmm, strange error, can't help you without more clarification?

Comment: @Herve can you add some screenshots connected with the eror or some code example?

Comment: `public getAllDetails() {
    let resp = this.authService.getDetails();
    resp.subscribe(resp => {
      this.dataSource.data = resp.reduce((acc, item) => {
        acc.push(...item.dechets); // error here
        console.log(item.dechets);
        return acc;
      }, []);
    });
  } `

Comment: I think your IType is defined in wrong way? can you share your Itype code as well?

Comment: ` export interface Itype {

    date_collect: number;
    code_client: number
    dechets: {
        type: string;
        weight: number
    }
} `

Comment: change it to ```export interface Itype { date_collect: number; code_client: number dechets: { type: string; weight: number }[] } ```

Comment: glad to help no problem